# How can i use python packages(that are only installed in my virtual env) while being in sublime text 3?

Tags: python, package, virtualenv, sublimetext3

In other words, how can i build a system using python from virtual environment where i got all my packages installed.
Ty in advance!

Comment: Assuming you're running your code from terminal, simply activate your virtual env with the installations and run your code how you normally would.

Comment: did you create any new environment or what?

Comment: just c\user\desktop\folder_name\virtualenv_name\scripts\activate.bat p.e

Comment: I think there are already plenty of resources available on how to use virtual environments (and using them with Sublime Text), which part of this specific situation is not covered by those?

Comment: @Joao the top three answers in the duplicate I linked have all three of the methods I would recommend -- adding the path of the Python executable to the project, using the `Virtualenv` package I linked to in my answer, and creating a custom build system. Personally, I would go for the project solution, but the plugin is also a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but it looks like the [`Virtualenv`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Virtualenv) package in Package Control does exactly what you're looking for. Please read through the README thoroughly, as it explains how the package works and which settings need to be set manually so that it will work.

Essentially, what it's doing under the hood is finding the Python executable in your virtualenv and creating a custom [build system](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html) with the path to that executable, so the proper modules will be accessible during the build. It claims to work with both `venv` and `virtualenv` environments.

Comment: I already went to that page but it didnt work. However, this time around, sublimerepl method worked just fine! Ty!